# What is the proper way to specify a QObject connection as unique?

Tags: c++, qt, enums

[Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) provides the following values for Qt::ConnectionType:

```
AutoConnection = 0;
DirectConnection = 1;
QueuedConnection = 2;
BlockingQueuedConnection = 4;
UniqueConnection = 0x80;
```

Clearly this shows that you can have a connection that is both `BlockingQueuedConnection` and `UniqueConnection`. However, merely combining these two with the `|` operator results in the compiler error:

```
connect(foo, SIGNAL(bar()), this, SLOT(bar()),
        BlockingQueuedConnection | UniqueConnection));
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Qt::ConnectionType'
```

So the parameters must be casted:

```
connect(foo, SIGNAL(bar()), this, SLOT(bar()),
        (Qt::ConnectionType) (BlockingQueuedConnection | UniqueConnection)));
```

Casting *feels* wrong in this situation for some reason. Is that really the appropriate way to make a unique blocking queued connection?

Answer (score 1):

`Qt::ConnectionType` is not a flag. You can't use `|` operator on them. You can only specify one enum value at once.

Comment: It is not a flag, but you can use '|' operator. Even [documentation encourages to do so](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum): `This is a flag that can be combined with any one of the above connection types, using a bitwise OR.`

Answer (score 1):

```
Qt::UniqueConnection 0x80
```

"This is a flag that can be combined with any one of the above connection types, using a bitwise OR.

When `Qt::UniqueConnection` is set, `QObject::connect()` will fail if the connection already exists (i.e. if the same signal is already connected to the same slot for the same pair of objects).
This flag was introduced in Qt 4.6." (from Qt5.0 document, http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Comment: Note that this note was added to Qt documentation at 5.0 version. In 4.8 docs UniqueConnection is a regular enum value and cannot be combined with other options.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only viable solution is casting, I used something like:

```
static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection)
```

in my code and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Qt bug, [documentation says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) one thing: `This is a flag that can be combined with any one of the above connection types, using a bitwise OR.`, practice show something else. At least `QObject::connect` code [looks fine](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L3011-3011).

Looks like there should be some feature request or bug report to Qt.

I would fix this like this by defining a function:

```
inline Qt::ConnectionType unique(Qt::ConnectionType typeOfConnection) {
    return static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(typeOfConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection);
}
```

Since IMO this case would look better with it:

```
connect(foo, SIGNAL(bar()), this, SLOT(bar()),
        unique(Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, `UniqueConnection` is like `AutoConnection`; So I guess you only have to specify `Qt::UniqueConnection`, and that's it. Qt will detect if you deal with different threads and behave accordingly.

Comment: The default for cross-thread connections is QueuedConnection though, not BlockingQueuedConnection.